# How to post user generated photos to Facebook using Koala?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, koala

I'm using the Koala gem in a Rails 3.2 app.

I'm trying to post an action that includes a user generated photo to a Facebook application. According to [FB's docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/usergeneratedphotos/), the url I need to post to is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/uid/namespace:action?object=http://path/to/page&image[0][url]=http://path/to/image.jpg&image[0][user_generated]=true
```

If I test this manually using Facebook's debugger, it works perfectly. But I'm having trouble achieving this with Koala.

I'm using the following method:

```
Koala::Facebook::API.new(app_token).put_connections( uid, namepsace:action, url )
```

If I use:

```
url = "http://path/to/page"
```

then the action is posted to Facebook correctly, but without the user generated photo.

If I use:

```
url = "http://path/to/page&image[0][url]=http://path/to/image.jpgimage[0][user_generated]=true"
```

I receive an error in the logs

```
#<Koala::Facebook::APIError: OAuthException: (#3502) Object at URL http://path/to/page&image[0][url]=http://path/to/image.jpg&image[0][user_generated]=true has og:type of 'website'. The property 'object' requires an object of og:type 'namespace:object'.  (http response code: 404)>
```

What is the correct way to construct the required post url using Koala? Or what is a good approach to begin debugging my current code? Or am I totally on the wrong track with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled a ton with this too, both because of Facebook's documentation and Koala's which are not super clear in my opinion:

```
Koala::Facebook::API.new(access_token).put_connections(
  uid,
  "namespace:action",
  "product" => "[URL_TO_PRODUCT]",
  "image[0][user_generated]" => true,
  "image[0][url]" => "[URL_TO_USER_GENERATED_IMAGE]",
  "fb:explicitly_shared" => true,
  "message" => "[DESCRIPTION]"
)
```

The other thing was that the target URL had to have `og:type="namespace:product"`

Hope this helps

Comment: I agree with you, the docs are not very clear. I ran into difficulties with working out the correct format (yours above is right). I also had trouble because I was trying to queue the method using queue_classic. Initially I was using symbols e.g. `:product`, which queue_classic does not like. Switching to strings as in your example fixed everything!

Comment: This answer no longer works. They may have made changes to the API.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your url in Facebook Debugger?
http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

From error message you got it looks like you should set **og:type** to **namespace:object** and to get custom image you should set **og:image** to **http://your.domain.com/path/to/user/generated/image**

Comment: thanks vlado. yes i have checked the url in debugger. If i construct the url manually, it works fine and I can post to timeline. The problem I'm having is how to recreate that url with Koala. I can get a normal post working, but if I try to modify the url to add `&image[0][url]=http://path/to/image&image[0][user_generated]=true` i receive an error. Any idea how to construct this url with koala?

Comment: I would start from [here](https://github.com/arsduo/koala/blob/master/lib/koala/http_service.rb#L42). Try calling Koala.make_request(...) directly from rails console and/or open koala gem (bundle open koala) and add some debugging here to see exact call sent to Facebook when you run put_connections method

Comment: thanks Vlado, I have been digging through the source to try an figure out how the gem works, but debugging and stepping through is a good suggestion. thanks. I'll let you know what I find

Answer (score 0):

I was using put_connections, like you, but it's not necessary, you can use the method **put_wall_post**.

I asked for the permission: **publish_actions**.

And in my Controller's method I have:

```
api = Koala::Facebook::API.new(@oauth_token)
api.put_wall_post("Testing post on Timeline", {
    :name => "Im a wall post",
    :link => "http://www.example.com",
    :caption => "Im a caption",
    :description => "Im a long description of an attachment",
    :picture => "http://www.example.com/picture.jpg" 
}, @users_facebook_id)
```

With this, you can post to the user's Timeline, having an image, a description, etc.